# It stops listening when there is a sound gap in the text to speech application

Tags: java, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am coding an application to have a text printed to the editText when it is read. My application works, but the application stops listening during pauses while reading the text.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;

ImageView imageView;
TextView textView;


public static Integer RecordAudioRequestCode=1;

private SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
imageView=findViewById(R.id.image);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        checkPermission();
    }
    speechRecognizer=SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

    Intent speechIntent=new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS,50000000);

    speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_mic_none_24);
            ArrayList<String> arrayList=bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            editText.setText(arrayList.get(0));
        }
        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });

    imageView.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
        if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            speechRecognizer.stopListening();
        }
        if (motionEvent.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_mic_none_24);
            speechRecognizer.startListening(speechIntent);
        }
        return false;
    });
}

private void checkPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},RecordAudioRequestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    speechRecognizer.destroy();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode==RecordAudioRequestCode && grantResults.length>0){
        if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

}